# метод гаусса для прямоугольных матриц

Tags: c++

много гуглил на эту тему, нашел код для решения матриц размера n на n+1 а что делать если матрица размера к примеру 3 на 10?

```
double* G(double a[][y], double r[],fstream &Write)
{
    double arr[x][y];
    double res[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        res[i] = r[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }

    double* mas, max;
    int k, index;
    const double eps = 0.00001;  // точность
    mas = new double[x];
    k = 0;
    while (k < x)
    {
        // Поиск строки с максимальным a[i][k]
        max = abs(arr[k][k]);
        index = k;
        for (int i = k + 1; i < x; i++)
        {
            if (abs(arr[i][k]) > max)
            {
                max = abs(arr[i][k]);
                index = i;
            }
        }
        // Перестановка строк
        if (max < eps)
        {
            // нет ненулевых диагональных элементов
            cout << "Решение получить невозможно из-за нулевого столбца ";
            cout << index+1 << " матрицы A" << endl;
            Write << "Решение получить невозможно из-за нулевого столбца ";
            Write << index + 1 << " матрицы A" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {
            double temp = arr[k][j];
            arr[k][j] = arr[index][j];
            arr[index][j] = temp;
        }
        double temp = res[k];
        res[k] = res[index];
        res[index] = temp;
        // Нормализация уравнений
        for (int i = k; i < x; i++)
        {
            double temp = arr[i][k];
            if (abs(temp) < eps) continue; // для нулевого коэффициента пропустить
            for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
                arr[i][j] = arr[i][j] / temp;
            res[i] = res[i] / temp;
            if (i == k)  continue; // уравнение не вычитать само из себя
            for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
                arr[i][j] = arr[i][j] - arr[k][j];
            res[i] = res[i] - res[k];
        }
        k++;
    }
    // обратная подстановка
    for (k = x - 1; k >= 0; k--)
    {
        mas[k] = res[k];
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            res[i] = res[i] - arr[i][k] * mas[k];
    }
    return mas;
}
```

Comment: А что вы хотите получить для матрицы 3x10? Все, что вы можете - это получить матрицу, в которой в левой части будет единичная матрица 3x3.

Comment: мне нужно получить с матрицы 3 на 10 решение СЛАУ

Comment: Т.е. Вы хотите получить 10 неизвестных с помощью системы всего из трёх уравнений?

Comment: При двух уравнениях и трёх переменных решение будет для двух переменных с параметрическим решением. `a(c)=D-E*c , b(c)=F-G*c`. `c` - может быть любым, если матрица уравнений позволяет.

Comment: Увы, при недоопределенной системе линейных уравнений вы не сможете получить единственное решение; в лучшем случае вы получите три переменные, выражаемые через линейные комбинации остальных. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта проблема не имеет математического решения.

Число строк в матрице представляет собой число имеющихся у вас уравнений.
Количество столбцов - это количество переменных.

Вам нужно иметь по крайней мере столько же уравнений, сколько у вас есть переменных (при условии, что уравнения не являются линейными комбинациями друг друга).

пример:

> 1 . x + 1 . y = 10
>   1 . x + 0 . y = 5

У нас есть 2 уравнения и 2 переменные, и система уравнений может быть решена.

пример:

> 1 . x + 1 . y = 10

Это имеет бесконечные решения (0, 10 и 1, 9 и 0.001, 9.999 и т. д)

Если у вас больше уравнений, чем переменных (при условии, что у вас нет противоречивых уравнений), вы можете получить приближенное решение. Для этого я бы рекомендовал вам посмотреть метод наименьших квадратов.