# Неправильный подсчет в методе гаусса

Tags: c++, классы

Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку. У я нахожу вектор x из A*x=b, где А-матрица, b-вектор.
И при подсчете мне выдает неправильный результат.
Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Solver.h"
#include "cmath"
#define EPS 1e-3

Solver::Solver(const Matrix& A, const Vector& b, const Vector& x)
{
    this->A = A;
    this->b = b;
    this->x = x;
    len= x.GetLen();
}

Solver::Solver()
{
    std::cout << "Enter size: ";
    std::cin >> len;
    Matrix A(len, len);
    Vector x(len), b(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
        {
            std::cout << "A[" << i << "][" << j << "] = ";
            std::cin >> A[i][j];
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "b[" << i << "] = ";
        std::cin >> b[i];
    }
    this->A = A;
    this->x = x;
    this->b = b;
}

void Solver::MGauss()
{
    double a1, a2, c;
    Matrix CopyA = A;
    Vector Copyb = b;
    int k;

    for (k = 0; k < len - 1; k++)
    {
        int nR = CopyA.maxnR(k, k);
        CopyA.swap(k, nR);
        Copyb.swap(k, nR);
        a1 = CopyA[k][k];

        for (int i = k + 1; i < len; i++)
        {
            a2 = CopyA[i][k];
            c = a2 / a1;
            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
                CopyA[i][j] -= CopyA[k][j] * c;
            Copyb[i] -= Copyb[k] * c;
        }
    }

    for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int j = i; j < len; j++)
        {
            sum += CopyA[i][j] * x[j];
        }
        x[i] = (Copyb[i] - sum) / CopyA[i][i];
    }

}

void Solver::PrintM()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
        {
            std::cout.width(7);
            std::cout.precision(2);
            std::cout << std::fixed << A[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout.precision(2);
        std::cout << "| " << std::fixed << b[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

void Solver::PrintX()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "x" << i << " = " << x[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

bool Solver::Check()
{
    Vector tmp = A * x;
    return tmp == b;
}
```

Comment: Метод гаусса нельзя реализовывать на числах типа double. Об этом предупреждают во всех методичках. Только простые дроби. Промежуточные вычисления нельзя округлять, или терять точность. Любое округление или потеря точности бесконечная дробь после запятой - приводит к тому что метод "не сходится".

Comment: Только специально-подогнаные числа, такие что бы при вычислениях всё делилось нацело могут дать положительный результат. Я у вас **не вижу исходные данные** т.е. матрицу. Можно просчитать решение на бумаге, и то что на ПК будет сходится с тем что на бумаге, если не сходится - то небольшими правками всё легко можно поправить (если  реализовано через простые дроби или особые подогнанные числа). Так же есть сайты которые расписывают решение в режиме онлайн.

Comment: Зачем вам эпсилон, может вы что-то напутали, метод Гаусса не использует эпсилон. Почитайте приближённые методы решения СЛР. Посмотрите так же https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1135577/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86?rq=1